# Setting PS1 on macOS Catalina causes Terminal prompt to overlap itself when window is resized

Tags: bash, terminal, macos

I've set PS1 in my .bash_profile, and while the colors work I get awful word wrapping and weird line behavior when I resize my Terminal window size.

Here is my .bash_profile:

```
[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin:${PATH}"

shopt -s checkwinsize
export PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3
export PS1='\[\e[0;37m\]\d \D{} \[\e[36m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\[\e[32m\]\h:\[\e[0;31m\]\w\[\e[m\] \$ '
export CLICOLOR=1
# export LSCOLORS=AxcxcxdxBxegedabagahad    # light theme
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced  # dark theme
alias ls='ls -GFh'
alias mv='mv -iv'
alias cp='cp -iRv'
```

Is there something wrong with the way I have set PS1?

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily recover a normal terminal, you can use:

```
kill -28 $$
```

You must put [ and ] around any non-printing escape sequences in your prompt. Thus:

```
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
purple=$(tput setaf 5)
reset=$(tput sgr0)
export PS1="\[$blue\]\h:\[$purple\]\w\[$reset\]\\$ "
```

So stop using raw ansi codes, it's not readable, better use `tput`.

Check 
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053

Comment: Your code works fine as is, but once I add the date (e.g. `\D{%F %T}`) I start getting word wrap issues again when I resize the window (and the same behavior with long directory names with `\w`). Is there a way around this?